# Software Update crashes

Tags: apt, update-manager, software-sources

Whenever I click "install now" on new updates - it starts running and promptly crashes.

What can I do about this? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

This is the error I get:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:2
```

Comment: Pleas update your question with the commands and output from commands. We can not guess what goes wrong on your machine.

Comment: when I do apt-get update through the command line this is where it falls :

Comment: The error (or Warning as it is) says that the same ppa is define twice in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` in line 1 and line two. Fix that by commenting out, or delete one of the lines. Since it is only a warning, it shouldn't stop you from updation or installing packages.